# Put and get a map from Libgdx preferences

Tags: java, dictionary, libgdx, preferences

Hey I'm having problems with getting the information from a preferences file in libgdx.  I put a map in with some coords so that I can position some stuff, but when I get the map from the preferences file (which gets the entire file, not just the map I put in) and I can't read the coords that I put in.
I can get the keys from the map no problem, but when I try to access the value from the map I get a runtime error java.lang.String cannot be cast.  I've tried different values like Vector2, and Float[] but I get the same error

Heres my code:

```
public class SetSettings {
private Actor actor;
private Actor hit;
private Sprite sprite;
private Sprite sprite2;
private Rectangle rect;
private boolean customHit = false;
private ShapeRenderer render = new ShapeRenderer();
Array<Actor> actors = GameScreen.buttons.stage.getActors();

public SetSettings() {
    setOriginal();
    setCustom();
    rect = new Rectangle();
}

public void setOriginal() {
    learnGame.ass.settings.get().clear();
    float height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    float width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    // ui settings
    java.util.Map<String, Coords> map = new HashMap<String, Coords>();
    map.put("hpBar", new Coords(width - (learnGame.ass.hpBar.getWidth() * 1.02f), height - (height * .076f)));
    map.put("hpBase", new Coords(learnGame.ass.hpBar.getX(), learnGame.ass.hpBar.getY()));

    for (Entry<String, Coords> key : map.entrySet())
        System.out.println(key.getValue().x); // works fine here

}

public void setCustom() {
    java.util.Map<String, ?> amap =  learnGame.ass.settings.get();
    for (Entry<String, ?> key : amap.entrySet())  {
        if (key.getValue() instanceof Coords) {
            Coords coords = (Coords) key.getValue();
            float x_value = coords.x;
            float y_value = coords.y;
            System.out.println("6" + key.getKey());
            System.out.println("" + x_value);// <-----------error here -- java.lang.String cannot be cast to anything..

    }

}

public class Coords {
    float x;
    float y;

    public Coords(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the exact full error message?

Comment: are you using [libgdx preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) format? or you've implemented your own storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the API doc - libgdx does not support array or collection or objects (other than String) in [libgdx preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences). If you intend to use exactly libgdx format - consider flattening your complex structure into associated array of Strings or primitive types.

```
preferences.putFloat("hpBar_x", 123f);
preferences.putFloat("hpBar_y", 456f);
```

Comment: Dang alright, I just had thought that I could put in a map with anything i wanted :/  alright well I guess I'll have to do that, thanks!